# How to put timestamp using update in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

I'd like to update a column and put a timestamp, but I can't figure out how to do it...
It should be something like this:

```
"UPDATE `j25_vikevents_orders` SET `checkins` = \"{\"'$p'\": TIMESTAMP}\" WHERE scode = '$scode' AND id = '$oid'";
```

So I get something like this:

```
{"1": 1403252036}
```

Comment: is `{"1": 1403252036}` is timestamp?

Comment: 1403252036 should be the timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MySQL and a Unix timestamp, something like...

```
 ..SET `checkins` =  FROM_UNIXTIME(\"{\"'$p'\": TIMESTAMP}\")...
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime for more

The value "1403252036" in human terms is "Fri, 20 Jun 2014 08:13:56 GMT"

Answer (score 0):

So short a few details, but with a few assuming the following:

- This is PHP Code
- You are connecting to a MySQL Database
- You want the MySQL server to supply the date time
- You want to supply the first number
- $p is a safe numeric variable and NOT from user input

You could rewrite as something like the following:

```
"UPDATE `j25_vikevents_orders` SET `checkins` = CONCAT('{\"$p\": ', NOW(), '}') WHERE scode = '$scode' AND id = '$oid'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help. It was not exactly what I was looking for. Now I inserted strtotime("now").
BTW: all the assuming was right, next time I'll try to post that too :-)